# App icon does not support on OS 9 devices

Tags: android

App icon does not support on android 9 devices. Here I am sharing the code. Please reply of it:

```
    android:icon="@drawable/appicon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:roundIcon="@drawable/main_icon"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an icon automatically in Android Studio:

Go to menu File → New → Image Assets → select launcher icon → choose image file.

Answer (score 1):

```
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_logo_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
```

Try to use mipmap folder (i.e, create mipmap icon using existing image[image])for app icons